# Opening a web page from an Android application displays bad icons

Tags: javascript, android, typescript-generics

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQ2U8.png)

In Android application, when Facebook is not installed, a new window should be opened at the relevant URL,
It is opened but with a bad icon as seen in the attached screenshot.
Please advise.

```
this.appAvailability.check('com.facebook.katana').then(
  () => {// facebook is installed
    window.open('fb://page/my_app_123_id’, '_system', 'location=no');
  },
  () => {//no: boolean
    // lead to website instead of app if facebook app does not exists
    window.open('https://www.facebook.com/my_app_123/', '_blank', 'location=yes');
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by using inappbrowser options
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/